Statement about original function given its Fourier transform
I am taking a course in Fourier Theory and in an exercise in the lecture notes, it asks to determine whether the statement is true
$$If \ \hat{f}(\xi_1,\xi_2)=\frac{\sin(\xi_2)}{1+i\xi_1^2}$$ then $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$
My question is, in general, how can i make any statement about the original function given its fourier transform? I assume, in the case where the inverse Fourier transform (we just introduced it in class) is well defined, then I could make some statement about it. This seems really elementary, any help or references would be appreciated?

Since $\sin \xi_2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\xi_2 y}\mu(dy)$ is the Fourier transform of
$$\mu(dy)=\frac{1}{2i}(\delta_1-\delta_{-1})$$ the proposed function $\hat{f}(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ cannot be the Fourier transform of a function. In fact $\hat{f}(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ is the product of two functions of $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ alone. One is the FT of $$g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ix\xi_1}\frac{1-i\xi_1^2}{1+\xi_1^4}d\xi_1$$ you are dealing with the measure $g(x)dx\times \mu(dy)$ which is concentrated on the set $R\times \{-1,1\}$ of zero Lebesgue measure $dxdy$. Not a very interesting exercise which asks for something questionable.
